# from "heap memory" to "java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed"

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, tomcat

I have a little website that gets pics from a mysql DB (BLOB field) and then prints them on my webpages.

With some classes i read the blob fields, i cut them to make "square" pics, and with a servlet i print the pics on my pages.

In every pages i do it (read some blob fields, cut pics, print about 10 pics).

I have my own virtual machine on a server that i rented, and i have 64 mb of heap space.

From time to time, I started having this error:

```
"Exception in thread "http-bio-12418-exec-26" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space"
```

So, thinking my code was too "heavy", i edited it. Now, from time to time, i get this error in tomcat log:

```
    Feb 10, 2014 7:23:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [] threw exception [javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed] with root cause
java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkClosed(ResultSetImpl.java:794)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.next(ResultSetImpl.java:7139)
    at org.apache.jsp.NewsDinamic_jsp._jspService(NewsDinamic_jsp.java:104)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Feb 10, 2014 7:25:42 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [] threw exception [javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed] with root cause
java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkClosed(ResultSetImpl.java:794)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.next(ResultSetImpl.java:7139)
    at org.apache.jsp.News_jsp._jspService(News_jsp.java:174)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

But this error hasn't any sense. Im sure the problems is not with the database! If i refresh the page then the site keeps on working good. I'm sure i have to do something on the server.

P.S.: I deleted the JDBC library and all the other libraries i added to my porject from the lib folder of my site and i put them in tomcat lib folder, following some advices on this forum.

Comment: You are probably closing the connection and then try to use the resultset, post the relevant code so we can see what you're doing.

Comment: Show your code, especially after resultSet.close();

Comment: @fatman i added the error track

Comment: stacktrace is nice, but we need actual java code

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem in the Heap size so first you need to take a look at the JVM memory parameters. actually you can set the as much memory as you want to your JVM:

```
-Xmx2048m -> this param to set the max memory that the JVM can allocate
-Xms1024m -> the init memory that JVM will allocate on the start up
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M -> this for the max Permanent Generation memory
-XX:MaxNewSize=  -> this need to be 40% from your Xmx value
-XX:NewSize=614m -> this need to be 40% from your Xmx value
```

so first make sure that you set this arguments correctly, then edit your code if you still get `OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: How can i do that? the jvm is on a server i rented. Should i edit tomcat/bin/catalina.sh?

Comment: Yes, add them under `CATALINA_OPTS`, e.g: `CATALINA_OPTS="–Xmx2048m -Xms1024m"`

Comment: There's already this line   CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS $JPDA_OPTS".
Should i delete it just add  a new line?

Comment: No don't delete anything, just make sure that the line you are looking for is `export CATALINA_OPTS="Arguments"` and just add the arguments beside any thing else that already exist.

Comment: I turned this line  CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS $JPDA_OPTS" into this one  CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS $JPDA_OPTS –Xmx2048m -Xms1024m". But i still get the same error. I get this error just on thr server, when i test the site on my computer, it's perfect!

Comment: If you mean the error mentioned above : `java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed`, then reollback this change and test it again.

Comment: rollback? u mean decrease?

Comment: No i meant return the code as before your editing, you said : `So, thinking my code was too "heavy", i edited it. Now, from time to time, ...`